# Instagram is public but no one can see my tagged photos except me

Tags: instagram, instagram-tags

My account is public and all photos tagged are set to automatic. I can see the photos I've been tagged in on my account, but shows "no posts yet" when everyone else tries to view my photos. All my settings are correct and it should show up. I don't understand why no one can see these if I have no privacy settings against it.

Answer (score 2):

It shows "no posts yet" because I guess you have not post anything yet from your account. So when someone visit your profile they didn't see anything and it show "no posts yet".

Currently, there is no feature to allow to view photos that other people have been tagged in on their profile from the web.

In mobile app there is a section (below the profile details of a user, last option right hand side) "Photos of *username*", so when someone click on this section they would be able to see all the photos you are tagged.